# for-in statement

Tags: typescript

TypeScript docs say nothing about loop like `for` or `for-in`. From playing with the language it seems that only `any` or `string` variables are supported in `for` loop.

Why has this decision been made?

Why not use the type information and have strongly-typed iteration variable?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The for-in statement is really there to enumerate over object properties, which is how it is implemented in TypeScript. There are some [issues with using it on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays).

I can't speak on behalf of the TypeScript team, but I believe this is the reason for the implementation in the language.

Answer (score 159):

In Typescript 1.5 and later, you can use [`for..of`](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/for...of) as opposed to `for..in`

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

for (var number of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
}
```

Comment: for...in iterates the keys of the objects in the collection, while for...of is the correct approach for iterating the objects themselves

Comment: for..of does not give you an iterator. So, if you're doing something like comparing consecutive values in an array, for..of is not the correct solution, for..in is.  TypeScript is WRONG for artificially constraining how these constructs might be used.

Comment: just to add to this, if you need the index as well you can do `for (var [i, number] of numbers.entries()) { }`

Answer (score 76):

TypeScript isn't giving you a gun to shoot yourself in the foot with.

The iterator variable is a string because **it is a string**, full stop. Observe:

```
var obj = {};
obj['0'] = 'quote zero quote';
obj[0.0] = 'zero point zero';
obj['[object Object]'] = 'literal string "[object Object]"';
obj[<any>obj] = 'this obj'
obj[<any>undefined] = 'undefined';
obj[<any>"undefined"] = 'the literal string "undefined"';

for(var key in obj) {
    console.log('Type: ' + typeof key);
    console.log(key + ' => ' + obj[key]);
}
```

How many key/value pairs are in `obj` now? 6, more or less? No, 3, and all of the keys are strings:

```
Type: string
0 => zero point zero
Type: string
[object Object] => this obj; 
Type: string
undefined => the literal string "undefined"
```

Comment: OK... but a string is not as precise as "a key of this specific object". So how does one type keys of an object when iterating with a for in loop?

Comment: use for...of instead of for...in

Answer (score 24):

**edit 2018**: This is outdated, js and typescript now have for..of loops.
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

---

The book "TypeScript Revealed" says

"You can iterate through the items in an array by using either for or for..in loops as demonstrated here:

```
// standard for loop
for (var i = 0; i < actors.length; i++)
{
  console.log(actors[i]);
}

// for..in loop
for (var actor in actors)
{
  console.log(actor);
}
```

"

Turns out, the second loop does **not** pass the actors in the loop. So would say this is plain wrong. Sadly it is as above, loops are untouched by typescript.

**map** and **forEach** often help me and are due to typescripts enhancements on function definitions more approachable, lke at the very moment:

```
this.notes = arr.map(state => new Note(state));
```

My wish list to TypeScript;

1. Generic collections
2. Iterators (IEnumerable, IEnumerator interfaces would be best)