# Typescript type inference inside for loop

Tags: typescript

This looks like a problem with the typescript compiler, but not sure, maybe I do not understand typescript type inference. Can anybody explain this problem:

I have this simple code to do something on a list of "TypeAs".. the variable "item" is getting type "Any" when it is very clear that the list is of type "TypeA[]". So, to have type safety and intellisense I have to cast the type.

```
    var list: TypeA[] = this.getListOfTypeAs();
    for (var item in list) {
        var typedItem = (<TypeA> item); //clearly a problem with typescript
```

Why?

Answer (score 11):

As [pointed out by Zev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686984/188246) and stated in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The `for..in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.

In TypeScript 1.5+ you can use [`for...of`](https://github.com/dherman/tc39-codex-wiki/blob/master/data/es6/for-of/index.md) to iterate over the elements in an array:

```
var list: TypeA[] = this.getListOfTypeAs();
for (let item of list) {
    // item is an element of list in here
}
```

While in previous versions you can use a standard `for` loop:

```
var list: TypeA[] = this.getListOfTypeAs();
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var typedItem = item[i];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because Javascript's `for...in` iterates over the property names of an object/array, not the values of the properties.

- [Arrays on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [TypeScript for-in statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950681/typescript-for-in-statement).

Comment: Thanks.  I see. So, if I understood, still using "in", my code can be fixed using:     for (var i in list) {
        var typedItem = list[i];

Comment: @pabloelustondo it's not recommended. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500878/188246).