# How to Iterate Over String Indexed Array In TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I have defined a static property as such:

```js
private static colorsByName: { [index: string]: MyColorClass}
```

but when I attempt to use `for... of` from the answer listed here: [TypeScript for-in statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950681/typescript-for-in-statement)

```
for(let value of MyClass.colorsByName) {
    ...
}
```

I get an error:

> Type { [index: string]: MyColorClass; } is not an array type or a string type.

If I switch over to using `for in`, the error goes away, but `value` is typed as `any`.

```
for(let value of MyClass.colorsByName) {
    ...
}
```

What is the actual type of `value` in this case?  Ideally I'd like to loop through all values in the colorsByName property, either in a  pair approach, or just to get `MyColorClass` types returned.

```
for(let value of MyClass.colorsByName) {
    // value: MyColorClass
}
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not an array—it's an object with string keys and values of type `MyColorClass`.

What you can do, is turn it into an array by getting an array of the object's keys then mapping the keys to the properties of the object:

```
const colors = Object.keys(MyClass.colorsByName).map(key => MyClass.colorsByName[key]);
```

Since you might do this a lot, you could create a reusable function to turn the properties into an array:

```
function propsToArray<T>(obj: { [index: string]: T; } | { [index: number]: T; }) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(prop => obj[prop]);
}
```

Then you use it like so:

```
for (const color of propsToArray(MyClass.colorsByName)) {
    // use color here
}
```

Side note: You may just want to store this cached on a static property of `MyClass`.

### Object.values

Alternatively, you could also use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
for (const color of Object.values(MyClass.colorsByName)) {
    // use color here
}
```

But you might need to add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) if you use that.

Comment: So would `Object.keys(MyClass.colorsByName)` potentially return back, `"red","black","green"` then calling the map does a projection of that enumeration?

Comment: so `{ [index: string]: MyColorClass}` does not mean an array that is indexed by string, but rather an object whose properties are of type MyColorClass, and those properties are indexed by string?

Comment: the for..in (below, by @LukeMachowski ) seems to be better. Please consider to update correct answer

Comment: @JiangHongTiao generally using `Object.keys` is preferred over `for...in` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446317/188246)). In this situation I don't think it matters which one is used, but I just have a general rule of always using `Object.keys` so I don't run into any surprises.

Answer (score 7):

### for..in

When looking at the Typescript documentation ([Typescript: Iterators and Generators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)), we see that the for..in syntax will iterate over the **keys** of the object.

> for..in returns a list of keys on the object being iterated, whereas for..of returns a list of values of the numeric properties of the object being iterated.

We can use that to our advantage to index into our object and get the strongly typed value:

```
// Go through each key of the indexed object:
for (const key in indexedObject)
{
   // Get the indexed item by the key:
   const indexedItem = indexedObject[key];
   // Now we have the item.

   // Use it...
}
```

### Solution

We can use that to get an elegant solution to the question:

```
// Go through each named color:
for (const colorName in colorsByName)
{
   // Get the strongly typed color with this name:
   const color = colorsByName[colorName]; // : MyColorClass
   // Now we have the the strongly typed color with this name.

   // Paint the world in a techni-colour rainbow...
}
```