# Iterate through arrays in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, loops

I want to iterate through an array of objects and acces the property values of that iterated object in typescript.

Doing this in c#, it's just a matter of performing a foreach through the array.

In typescript this seems a bit different. We can do a foreach, but we dont have access to 'complete' object, how to do this?

```cs
@Input() gridDefinitions: GridColumnDefinition[]   
 public test() {
     for (var def **in** this.gridDefinitions){
       var test = <GridColumnDefinition>this.selectedObject;
       let castedtype = <GridColumnDefinition>def; // this gives an error
    }  
 }
```

UPDATE: I just ran into the solution. Problems lies in how to iterate through the collection. When using **of** in stead of **in** we can access the iterated object. See [TypeScript for-in statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950681/typescript-for-in-statement)

Comment: What you want to achieve after iteration, you can simply use `map and flat`

Comment: NOT use "var", use "let"

Comment: @Eliseo "let" seems another way of declaring a variable, but I cannot find a way how it can be solution to previous problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use foreach and give a type to `def`

```
gridDefinitions.forEach((def: GridColumnDefinition) => {
       var test = <GridColumnDefinition>this.selectedObject;
       let castedtype = <GridColumnDefinition>def;
 })
```

Comment: @Fre just a note the type annotation on `def` is unnecessary if `gridDefinitions` is of type `GridColumnDefinition[]`. `gridDefinitions.forEach( def  => {...}`)  will work as well

Answer (score 6):

The `for...in`  construct iterates over the keys of an object. To iterate over the items in an array you need to use `for..of`

```
for (var def of this.gridDefinitions){ // def is of the array item type no casting necessary 
    var test = <GridColumnDefinition>this.selectedObject;
}
```

You can also use array methods such as `forEach`/ `map`/`reduce` to work with arrays in a manner similar to `LINQ` if you want.