# Typecript recursive types

Tags: typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to type the following function without using `any`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=33&pln=17&pc=36#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWeA5gDTa4ENn4CuRARhNRY5KAYwD21TpmG4wdEuTw9%20g1lAC%20Q2XQBeUtbgBmtalXLTclqABNaFcVzzBFygQY1r12L1mwQAHmASwFDieFRQNLREUKgAFO5EIADyvABW5HCIkNgAlJkISLEAfOjuYRFRRABKECJcprQAbihQcWLp5AR4ILklZTJWUIYSbQA2ECEA1hAgUPRQHWl9FkNrtIZtSwDaMyAAulAAZEeRSGKbO3uHyLdQAORLdcD3x6cAhACC1NQEIAB0dm%20vxA7XSu1m%201yK3cazWVVq9UaLTBaQhB1yAG5YXD1FAIGMKNBVnC4Rs2qBIBdFuDrrE7vcqHRGPcYYNSaSrpDYjS0dd-lU4licRyPOzcSKxaTJMAGnhedjBupFe4ZXLIvJEQ0KM0IHEkqllorldggA)

```
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  score: {
    prime: number,
  },
  prize: {
    first: {
      discount: number
    }
  }
}

export const trim = (
    myObj: MyType
): MyType => {
    const trimRecursive = (obj: any) => {
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                trimRecursive(obj[key]);
            } else {
                if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
                    obj[key] = obj[key].trim();
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };

    return trimRecursive(myObj);
};
```

Comment: Where are you using `any`?

Comment: sorry, I made an edit to my question, (obj :any)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun), as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12982438/6862530) points out, but here's how I did it. I used `forEach` to be able to assign a type.

```
export const trim = <T>(myObj: T):T => {
  const trimRecursive = <T>(obj: T): T => {
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((key) => {
      if (
        obj && typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key])
      ) {
        trimRecursive(obj[key])
      } else {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
          obj[key] = (obj[key] as unknown as string).trim() as unknown as T[keyof T]
        }
    }
  })
    return obj
  }
  return trimRecursive(myObj)
}
```